How will and how to use singing vibrato help riff and runs especially with vocal runs note separation?
Soo I'm learning vibrato and I can do riff and runs but sometimes had bad separation.. I'm thinking that maybe somehow learning vibrato will help me but will it actually and how?
I'm learning from this website:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.danielvocalcoaching.com/amp/how-to-practice-vocal-runs-riffs
"It is not by chance that most singers who can riff like that have great, fast vibrato (i.e. pulsation vibrato).
The connection between the two lies in the movement of the larynx.
Unlike the laryngeal vibrato, in which there’s a mild change of pitch, the pulsation vibrato has a different larynx movement that slightly “shakes” the same note.
It is this movement that creates the grid.
for more information about the different types of vibrato click here."
I'm learning vibrato now..
And thankfully successed to sing with natural, unconscious vibrato by holding long notes using diapraghmatic breath..
The problem is, when I sing riff and runs the same way I did my vibrato, the vocal runs just rather than being better but actually worse (it slides too much, messy, no separation of the notes) than what I usually do with my vocal runs before (I articulate using my diapraghm just like what you do with a legato/staccato but in the middle of it; in other words, delineation or the middle of a legato and staccato, not too choppy and not too connected)
Am I doing something wrong or does natural vibrato actually doesn't help anything at all when it comes to runs?

One thing to think about: different genres can approach vibrato differently. The "bel canto" tradition of opera has vibrato sort of "on all the time, by default." Earlier baroque practice treated it as an ornament, like a trill or a "riff/run", that could be added to a note. Many modern genres including gospel, R & B, musical theatre and various shades of pop, take various approaches in between. I'd suggest that for your purposes you think of it in the baroque way, as an ornament, "off by default."

Also, I'll let a vocalist answer, but I would not try to use vibrato in fast runs (even on instruments!). I take the quote as meaning "practicing a rapid, wide vibrato gives you the same vocal agility that is useful in fast runs," not actually meaning you should switch it on during a run. (After all, get the vibrato wide enough and it's just a trill! I think of Prince—that sound that starts a long note straight and then switches on a vib so wide it's basically a trill.)

For singing runs it is helpful to add controlled diaphragmatic articulation (as explained in your other question). A controlled vibrato of intensity does a similar thing — thus being able to do a controlled vibrato is helpful for adding controlled articulation. Uncontrolled vibrato — well, not so much.
But I would strongly advice you against trying to do vibrato during a run. This will hinder you, because you’ll need to do two different things with your diaphragma.

Ohh, some people said the note separation s in runs are natural once jaw is relaxed (open throat singing maybe?).. so it wasn't true?

@Whatssuppp That is definitely not true. What is true is that uncontrolled tension in your vocal apparatus will hinder flexibility a lot.

Thank you so much Sir! May I ask, now I can do runs cleanly but I have mild tensions, any tips? Or is it just open throat singing and all the tongue, etc. That's need to be done?
